# c++ Calling the overridden function of the child class instead of the parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I'm trying to call the method convert(double) from my child class: Kilogram. How would I go about calling the overridden function rather than the original. Below is my code for my three classes.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Conversion.cpp"

using namespace std;

int userInput;


Conversion con;

void menu() {
    cout << "Select an option: " << endl;
    cout << "1) KG to Lbs " << endl;
    cout << "2) Celsius to Kelvin " << endl;
    cout << "3) Teaspoons to millilitres " << endl;
    cout << "4) Multiplication tables (x) " << endl;
    cout << "5) Powers Tables (x) " << endl;
    cout << "6) Exit " << endl;

    cin >> userInput;

    switch(userInput) {
        case 1:
            cout << con.convert(23.56);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};

int main() {
    menu();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Conversion.cpp

```
class Conversion {
public:
    Conversion::Conversion(void) {

    }

    virtual double Conversion::convert(double varrr){

        return varrr;
    }
};
```

Kilogram.cpp

```
#include "Conversion.cpp"

double pounds;

class Kilogram : public Conversion {
public:
    Kilogram::Kilogram() {

    }

    virtual double Kilogram::convert(double kilos) override {
        pounds = (kilos * 2.2);
        return pounds;
    }

};
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why *would* it be called? Your program doesn't even *create* any `Kilogram` objects, much less call their functions.

Comment: Exactly, I'm confused how to go about doing this. I've spent a couple hours creating Kilogram objects and trying to call the convert() method, but no result and I receive a large amount of errors.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is calling the base definition is because in:

```
Conversion con;
```

... both the declared type and the runtime type are of the base type. To invoket the overridden method, the runtime type must be of the given derived type, and the declared type needs to  either be the derived type or it needs to be a  pointer or reference to the base type. That is:

```
Kilogram from_kilogram;
Conversion from_pounds;
Conversion* converter = &from_pounds;
if (is_kilograms) {
  converter = &from_kilogram;
}
result = converter->Convert(weight_in_pounds);
```